# MySQL very long query, inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

i developed a website where two team can face each other. The first team create a match search `m` for a certain `value` (stack), with `status` = search. The first team has a `elo` (level) attribute.
When the second team (which have a elo of 150) will search a match, we execute the following query:

```
SELECT m.id, m.value, m.teamOneScore, m.teamTwoScore, m.date, m.status, m.detail, m.team_one_id, m.team_two_id 
FROM user_match m
INNER JOIN team t ON m.team_one_id = t.id 
WHERE t.id = m.team_one_id 
    AND t.id <> 3        // You don't want to play against your own team
    AND t.elo <= 200     // 50 of elo range for example
    AND t.elo >= 100 
    AND m.value = '0.5'  
    AND m.status = 'search'
LIMIT 1
```

The problem is that this query is very long even if we only have 15000 user_match (there are only 40 rows that answer the requirements with value = 0.5, status = search) and 15000 teams (there are 5570 teams that answer the requirements with elo and id)
I tried to `EXPLAIN` the request, and here is the result:

[image]

If there is no opponent when a user searches a match, the request can take like 3 minutes, and this time will be reduce when the same request is executed many times (cache ?), and it's faster if there is an opponent.

The last thing I could precise is that user_match table contains a `detail` attribute that contains an heavy json_array ONLY IF the match status = ended

Do you know if it's the regular execution time ? What could I do to improve that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't repeat the condition on `t.id = m.team_one_id`.  So, this is your query:

```
SELECT m.id, m.value, m.teamOneScore, m.teamTwoScore, m.date, m.status, m.detail, m.team_one_id, m.team_two_id 
FROM user_match m INNER JOIN
     team t
     ON m.team_one_id = t.id 
WHERE t.id <> 3 AND     // You don't want to play against your own team
      t.elo <= 200 AND    // 50 of elo range for example
      t.elo >= 100 AND
      m.value = '0.5' AND
      m.status = 'search'
LIMIT 1;
```

Second, the query looks suspicious because you have `LIMIT` with no `ORDER BY`.  Typically, you want an `ORDER BY` so the row you return is guaranteed to be the same on each execution.

Indexes are how you speed queries.  I would start with the following indexes:

- `user_match(status, value, team_one_id)`
- `team(id, elo)`

The index on `user_match` is the best for that table based on the `where` clause.  Note:  If `value` is a number, then do not use single quotes around the `0.5`, that can confuse the optimizer.

The second index on `team` is not necessary if `id` is declared as the primary key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Indeed it looks suspicious but we know that by default it should order by user_match id and that's what we want. Concerning the repetition of the condition, it was a mistake 
I tried to index the user_match fields `status, value, team_one_id` and it takes only 0.02 seconds to query (after clearing the cache) ! 
Thank you !

Comment: @QuentinLerebours . . . There is no "default" ordering.  SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  If you need an ordering in a result set, you need to use `order by`.

Comment: Thanks i'll use order by to be sure, but it was not an important point for finding matches
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Straight to the point, you need to index columns using in where clause.

According to explain, it seems mysql plans to use only pk as index. And your pk in where column is being used to exclude only single row. So, mysql will scan all table except single row.

In this case, you have to index elo column to make query plan scan least rows.

```
ALTER TABLE team ADD INDEX search(id, elo);
```

Then see query time.

+EDIT
it seems above solution doesn't improve query time much.

Here's another point. You need to place smaller ranged table first at your join clause. With above index, team table will be smaller. So query will looks like this.

```
SELECT m.id, m.value, m.teamOneScore, m.teamTwoScore, m.date, 
       m.status, m.detail, m.team_one_id, m.team_two_id
FROM team t
INNER JOIN user_match m ON m.team_one_id = t.id 
WHERE 
t.elo <= 200     // 50 of elo range for example
AND t.elo >= 100
AND t.id <> 3        // You don't want to play against your own team
AND m.value = '0.5'  
AND m.status = 'search'
LIMIT 1
```

let me see if this works for you

Comment: I cleared mysql cache, i tried without index it took 5.8 seconds (i don't know why but it was faster than sometimes), i created the index on elo, it took 5.3 seconds. I added index on team id, it took 5.2
Do you think it's the regular time for this kind of query ?
Now i have to understand why sometimes it takes more than 1 minute

Comment: do you have index or foreign key on team_one_id column?

Comment: i can say it's not a regular time for joining tables with 15000 row

Comment: team_one_id is a foreign key to team table

Comment: Others saying you are repeating where condition. Did you remove it and saw some improvement?

Comment: I did note another answer as the good one, what improve a lot my request was to index user_match field like team_one_id, status and value
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try by giving index to the columns which are mostly queried like the column are `currently present in where condition.`..

if they are not indexed then u can just try the 'alter query to add index to the column' and then see the response time.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need t.id = m.team_one_id in the where clause when you used it in the join clause (INNER JOIN team t ON m.team_one_id = t.id)? I believe this is redundant.

I think that you should move the team filters in the ON clause and get something like this

```
SELECT m.id, m.value, m.teamOneScore, m.teamTwoScore, m.date, m.status, m.detail, m.team_one_id, m.team_two_id 
FROM user_match m
INNER JOIN team t ON m.team_one_id = t.id and t.id <> 3 and t.elo <= 200 and t.elo >= 100
WHERE m.value = '0.5'  
    AND m.status = 'search'
LIMIT 1
```

Then add a composite index on the value and status column in the user_match table.

```
ALTER TABLE user_match ADD INDEX usermatchteam_idx(value, status);
```

and a index on the team table as mentioned in the comment above

```
ALTER TABLE team ADD INDEX elosearch_idx(id, elo);
```

Please try this approach.
If this doesn't help can you please provide the create tables for team and user_match tables so we can investigate further.